# Put checkboxes inside combobox for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to do [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx) in javascript without using jQuery?

Comment: Yes. If it's possible using `jQuery` (and I am reasonably sure it is), it's possible without. If you are asking for an implementation, have you tried implementing it yourself first? That seems like a rather general question.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that is possible in jQuery is possible in JavaScript, simply because jQuery is written in JavaScript. However, you would probably need to do a bit more work.

Specifically, for this, you will need to implement your own alternative for `<select/>`, laying out the drop-down box and its elements and handling the events inside by yourself.